# How do I get the bottom line in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get the line number of the bottom of the current screen. I've tried:

```
winsaveview()['topline'] + winheight(0) - 1
```

But this doesn't take into account folds.

How do I get the bottom line of the current screen in vimscript that takes into account folds?

Comment: Your "bottom line" is the line at the bottom of what? The current window? Do you want a screen line or a text line?

Comment: Good point, I've edited to clarify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `line()` with `w$` to get last line visible in current window

```
:echo line('w$')
```

For more help see `:h line()`